Загадки союза А
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Союз А часто упоминается в справочниках по правописанию, есть у него и грамматические особенности.  Может ли академическая грамматика как-то объяснить свойства этого союза?

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
ЧЕМ ИНТЕРЕСЕН СОЮЗ А

В грамматике союз А относится к группе сочинительных противительных союзов,   в то же время он  является основным сопоставительным союзом.
Союз "а" в предложениях

Конструкция НЕ...А называется противопоставлением,  но при этом мы сопоставляем признаки: отрицаем один и утверждаем другой: Дом не большой, а маленький. С другой стороны, конструкцию на основе главного противительного союза НО называют сопоставлением (уступительное значение): Дом небольшой, но уютный.

Перед союзом А всегда ставится запятая, но последний однородный член запятой не закрывается: Каждый вечер солнце садилось в море, а не в тучи и было при этом клюквенного цвета (Ю. К.).

На основе союза А образуется союз А ТАКЖЕ. Это тоже сочинительный союз с теми же свойствами, но у него есть особенности по значению. Когда используется союз А ТАКЖЕ

В правописании союз А проблемный, так как во многих темах приходится различать две основные функции союза: (1) союз А используется как обычный сочинительный союз в предложениях с однородными членами или однородными придаточными; (2) союз А соединяется со словами или речевыми оборотами (с деепричастным оборотом, с вводными словами и союзами), образуя единую конструкцию. Он начал приносить книги и старался читать их незаметно, а прочитав, куда-то прятал (М. Г.).
Запятая перед вводным словом.

В повседневной речи мы постоянно используем этот союз в начале темы или при переходе к другой теме, сопоставляя новое с уже сказанным раньше.
Союзы в начале предложения.

С помощью союза А строится сказочный зачин
В чем разница между присоединительными союзами "И" и "А"?
Почему в начале сказок иногда используют союз А, а не И


ЧЕМ  ОБУСЛОВЛЕНЫ ОСОБЕННОСТИ СОЮЗА А (материал из Русской корпусной грамматики)

Противительный союз А не имеет точных аналогов в других языках и переводится в разных контекстах по-разному – например, на английский как but или and.

Рассмотрим предложение: Он собирался поступать на медицинский, а передумал. Неправильная запись, здесь нужен  союз НО: Он собирался поступать на медицинский, но передумал.


А если так: Он собирался поступать на медицинский, а потом передумал. Теперь правильно, фантастика!

Но лингвисты называют это иначе: Союз А является лингвоспецифичным словом, показателем идеи отсутствия контроля субъекта над обстоятельствами. В предложениях с союзом А постоянно не хватает информации,  говорящий как бы удивлен и не понимает причин происходящего. Однако правило неконтролируемости работает не во всех случаях: достаточно расширить контекст, и фраза становится правильной. Соответственно, союз А часто работает в паре с другими словами.

Союз А  нужно правильно употреблять в речи, например:


Ее пригласили, а она не пришла (почему-то). Ее пригласили, но она не пришла (были причины). Шел дождь, а Коля не взял зонт (говорящий удивлен). Шел дождь, но Коля не взял зонт (это его решение).
Союз А указывает на незнание говорящим факторов, благодаря которым неожиданная ситуация все-таки имеет место.

О союзе АН

В академических грамматиках  союз АН  фиксируется как просторечный и устаревший (в сочетании с частицами не и нет), но в настоящее время он все же достаточно часто встречается: Тут бы и закончить трапезу, ан нет, традиции Рабле живы на берегах Сены.
В чем его особенности? У  субъекта были некоторые ожидания относительно ситуации, которые неожиданно для него опровергаются противоположным ожидаемому положением вещей. Но при этом в союзе АН заключено некоторое прагматическое «злорадство» – говорящий часто бывает удовлетворен обманом ожиданий:
Вот вы хотели, чтоб я ничего не получила, ан люди справедливые, по-иному рассудили.  Мне-то казалось, что это делалось ради искусства и новых знакомств с девочками, ан нет! Дошёл до двенадцатой страницы, хочет перевернуть её ― ан ничего не получается.
